# How many zeros does $f(z) = z^{12}-4z^8+9z^5-2z+1$ have in the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

How many zeros does $f(z) = z^{12}-4z^8+9z^5-2z+1$ have in the unit circle?

I am trying to use the argument principle, but it to compute the integral of $\frac{f'}{f}$ seems to be a nightmare. Then I am trying to use $Rouche's$ theorem to simplify the problem. But what $g(z)$ should I choose? Is there a general guideline for solving this sort of problem?

Comment: If you have a sum, and one term has the largest modulus on the boundary of the domain in question, it's usually a good idea to look at that.

Answer (score 3):

On the unit circle, $|9z^5|=9$ is strictly larger than $$|f(z) -9z^5|=|z^{12}-4z^8-2z+1|\leq 1+4+2+1=8$$so by Rouche's theorem $f(z)$ has exactly five zeroes within the unit circle (counted with multiplicity).